# In django admin how do you access a function in a child model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to access the thumbnail function of my Image model for preview in my tabularInline.

In admin.py

```
class BlogWidgetCarouselInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BlogWidgetCarousel
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ('display_as', 'thumb', 'print_thumbs',)

    def display_as(self, instance):
        return instance.display()
    display_as.allow_tags = True

    def thumb(self, instance):
        return instance.Image.thumb() #Does not work

    def print_thumbs(self, instance):
        return instance.print_thumb() #Neither does this
```

In models.py

```
class BlogWidgetCarousel(models.Model):
    entry = models.TextField()
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position")
    images = models.ManyToManyField("Image")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', )

    def display(self):
        return self.entry
    display.allow_tags = True

    def print_thumb(self):
        return self.images.thumb

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")

    def thumb(self):
        return '<a href="{0}"><img src="{0}"></a>'.format(MEDIA_URL + str(self.image))
    thumb.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `images` field on your `BlogWidgetCarousel` is a `ManyToManyField`, which returns a queryset of `Image` objects.

So, first, you need to see if you have any image instances to display, and then grab the first one, or whichever you want to use:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    . . .

    def thumb(self):
        return '<a href="{0}"><img src="{0}"></a>'.format(self.image.url)


class BlogWidgetCarouselInline(admin.TabularInline):
 . . .

    def thumb(self):
        images = self.images.all()
        if images:
            return images[0].thumb()
        return ''
```

In this example, an empty string is returned, but you could just as easily return a "default" thumbnail path. I'm not a big fan of rendering HTML in the Python code, so personally I would move that portion to a template fragment:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import mark_safe
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


class Image(models.Model)
    . . .

    def thumb(self):
        return mark_safe(render_to_string('_thumb.html', {'image': images[0].image}))


# _thumb.html

<a href="{{ image.url }}"><img src="{{ image.url }}"></a>
```